# HTML Zooming Issue

Tags: html, css, zooming

I have a question regarding HTML. Since I'm quite new to this I'm not sure if my way of coding is efficient. The main issue for me is how the page looks when the page is zoomed in on the browser, everything will become clustered and overlapped with each other. How should I code to fix this with just pure HTML and CSS?

**Here's some links to images:**

At 100% zoom, the page looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J4H6.jpg

At 150% zoom, the page looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Sjv.jpg

**Here's my code for the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Sample Site</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="logo">
      <img src="Website Logo.png" alt="Website Logo" height="180px" width="300px">
   </div>

   <div class="slogan">
      <font color="#bfbfbf"><p>Good music, good friends, the rich aroma of 
      <font color="red">Strawberry</font>, <font color="blue">Blueberry</font>, 
      <font color="orange">Peach</font>, <font color="purple">Grape</font>, and cool 
      <font color="green">Menthol</font>.</p>
      <p>Let our flavours enthrall you, as you rock the night away.</p></font>
   </div>
   <div class="sloganFooter">
         <font class="part1" color="#bfbfbf">Come and </font> 
         <font class="part2" color="aqua">DISCOVER EXCITEMENT!</font></h3>  
   </div>

   <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
         <li><p>HOME</p></li>
         <li><p>PRODUCTS</p></li>
         <li><p>VENDORS</p></li>
         <li><p>FAQ</p></li>
         <li><p>CONTACT</p></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="mainPageImage">
      <img src="Main Page.png" alt="Main Page Image">
   </div>   

   <div class="socialMediaLinks">
      <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" height="40px" width="40px" 
      style="margin-right:15px;">
      <img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" height="40px" width="40px" style="margin-right:15px;">
      <img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" height="40px" width="40px" 
      style="margin-right:15px;">
   </div>
   <div class="copyright">
      <font color="#bfbfbf">&copy;2014 E-Clear Limited. All rights reserved.</font>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's my code for the CSS:**

```
body
{
   background-image: url("Website BG.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center; 
   background-color: black;
}

ul
{
   list-style-type: none;
}

.logo
{   
   margin-left: 17.500em;
   margin-top: 2.500em;
}

.slogan
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 43%;
   top: 5%;
   font-size: 1.250em;
   font-family: Calibri;   
   line-height: 50%;   
}

.sloganFooter
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 65%;
   top: 15%;
}

.part1
{
   font-size: 1.250em;
}

.part2
{
   font-size: 1.500em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation
{
   position: absolute;
   color: #bfbfbf;
   left: 12%;
   top: 25%;
   font-size: 2.188em;
}

.mainPageImage
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 26%;
   top: 25%;
}

.socialMediaLinks
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 90%;
   left: 50%;
}

.copyright
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 95%;
   left: 46.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you don't want the user to scale, you can set the `user-scalable` attribute to "no":

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Use these tags to get your site to scale however you want.

Also, if your site is designed with [good responsive design](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/16-really-useful-responsive-design-tutorials-71410085) in mind, then zooming and scaling won't be as much of an issue.

#### Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative position for "mainPageImage" div. Chrome has also known problems with the zoom. Meta viewport i do not think changes anything.